# How to pass ssh/22 in a Nginx layer 4 config?

Tags: git, nginx, kubernetes, ssh, nginx-config

This is how I tried to build a layer 4 nginx load blancer, which passes the traffic to my three workers of a kubernetes cluster:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
  worker_connections 768;
}

stream {
    upstream http {
        server <ip1>:80;
        server <ip2>:80;
        server <ip3>:80;
    }
    upstream ssl {
        server <ip1>:443;
        server <ip2>:443;
        server <ip3>:443;
    }
    server {
        listen 80;
        proxy_pass http;
    }
    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass ssl;
    }
}

http {
    sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  gzip on;

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

In the cluster I have deployed *gitea*, which handley my repositories. To get access to those I need to handle port 22 so I can do something like `git clone git:/my/repo`.

How do I do the correct nginx config to pass port 22?

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, but to networking and deployment, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I see a number of problems in the question. 1) Port 22 usually belongs to SSH server which implements SSH protocol; I doubt you can pass SSH protocol through HTTP proxy. 2) To run `git clone git://my/repo` you need the server to implement Git protocol; not HTTP, not SSH — [Git protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#_the_git_protocol); it's implemented by [git-daemon](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-daemon); for HTTP you need `git clone http://my/repo`; for SSH `git clone ssh://my/repo` or `git clone user@my:repo`.